# How to block malicious ip in sonicwall using script or api call

Tags: security, firewall

I am using Sonicwall corporate firewall.On daily basis we received so many malicious IP. we are currently blocking the IP manually into sonicwall.
Is there any way to do this automatically on we receive malicious ip detection in slack ? I want to handle this automatically using scripts/api call etc

Looking for solution.

Comment: You don't say what _service_ receives the potentially malicious connections, but software such as `fail2ban` can parse many types of logs and block external hosts using the most common firewalls. I'm not turning this into a real answer as the question is quite vague.